# Twitter Bootstrap theme & iTunes app header

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap for a one page site at http://uniqueamb.biz/flyersaredead/ and the itunes smart app disappears on an ipad or iphone after a second because twitter bootstrap automatically scrolls down. How do I stop the automatic scroll to keep the app header in place?

Comment: What are you referring to as the itunes smart app?

Comment: Putting this code in: <meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=652116751"> to suggest the app when on the correct device.  It's a half inch header that gives a direct "Install" or "Open" link to the app the page is trying to sell.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would find out the html that the phone inserts into the page, you can do this with javascript inserting the whole html into a textarea after the itunes store block is added.

Then you can use css, or js to fix your issues, the bootstrap affix class might be a great way to keep this block on top of the page until it's Xed out.